# Script result in sqlContext on registered temp table in Scala has minor difference than using Reduce in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning Scala now, and notice something that I don't understand why, I have a result to be generated registered Temp Table via sqlContext on a DataFrame derived from a RDD, the RDD is from a hdfs file exported from mysql.

Raw hdfs data can be retrieved from here (2MB):
https://github.com/mdivk/175Scala/tree/master/data/part-00000

Here is the script used on mysql:

```
 select avg(order_item_subtotal) from order_items;
+--------------------------+
| avg(order_item_subtotal) |
+--------------------------+
|       199.32066922046081 |
+--------------------------+
```

On Scala:

sqlContext:

```
> scala> val res = sqlContext.sql("select avg(order_item_subtotal) from
> order_items")

> +------------------+ 
  |               _c0|
  +------------------+ 
  |199.32066922046081|
  +------------------+
```

So they are the same, exactly same, which is expected;

RDD (please use the data file from https://github.com/mdivk/175Scala/tree/master/data/part-00000):

```
val orderItems = sc.textFile("/public/retail_db/order_items")

val orderItemsRevenue = orderItems.map(oi => oi.split(",")(4).toFloat)

val totalRev = orderItemsRevenue.reduce((total, revenue) => total + revenue)
res4: Float = 3.4326256E7

val cnt = orderItemsRevenue.count 

val avgRev = totalRev/cnt
avgRev: Float = 199.34178
```

As you can see, the avgRev is 199.34178, not what we calculated above in mysql and sqlContext 199.32066922046081

I do not think this is an acceptable discrepancy but I could be wrong, am I missing anything here?

It would be appreciated if you can help me understand this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your mysql table is using double thus you could try to change:

```
val orderItemsRevenue = orderItems.map(oi => oi.split(",")(4).toFloat)
```

into

```
val orderItemsRevenue = orderItems.map(oi => oi.split(",")(4).toDouble)
```

since you need more  precise results you can use double instead of float. Float is 32bits and double 64 which makes it useful when memory usage is critical otherwise use almost always double.

Comment: Thank you Alexandros, now I got the result closer: Double: 199.32066533890927